# The service "sylius.factory.product" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sylius.translation.locale_provider"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I'm using Composer to try to install sylius onto an existing project. There is, for some reason, precisely zero documentation or information on how to do this, so I'm feeling through the dark here.

I've done "composer require sylius\product-bundle". When I put the bundles in my AppKernel, I see this error:

The service "sylius.factory.product" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sylius.translation.locale_provider".

Google returns 0 results.

If I try to do composer require sylius\translation-bundle, I get more errors, something about not being able to convert a non-static method to a static one.

Comment: Better not to use sylius bundles yet it's in alpha stage. Even if you install it successfully some features won't work. I dropped it several times in my projects for this reason.

Comment: Thanks, yeah in the end I did likewise and decided to just write my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

You did not enable all the required bundles in your `AppKernel`, since almost all bundles of Sylius depend on `SyliusResourceBundle` (this is where translation services of Sylius live). I suggest you follow the installation guide and make sure you configured it all correctly as described. See: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusProductBundle/installation.html

If you have any further problems let me know and I will try to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your config.yml (thanks [pamil](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/5280))

```
sylius_resource:
    translation:
        enabled: true
        default_locale: "%locale%"
```

I also needed to add following configs:

```
sylius_product: ~

sylius_archetype:
    resources:
        product:
            subject: Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product
            attribute: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Attribute
            option: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Option
            archetype:
                classes:
                    model: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Archetype

sylius_association:
    resources:
        product:
            subject: %sylius.model.product.class%
            association:
                classes:
                    model: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ProductAssociation
```

Use [sylius.yml](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/sylius.yml) for reference when in trouble.
Also mind that the [sylius bundles need to be registered in specific order](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/1457) - It's easy to overlook. The docs put most emphasis on Doctrine being the last, but the order of Sylius bundles is no less important.

Here's my AppKernel for reference:

```
$bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
    new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
    new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
    new WhiteOctober\PagerfantaBundle\WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle(),
    new Bazinga\Bundle\HateoasBundle\BazingaHateoasBundle(),
    new winzou\Bundle\StateMachineBundle\winzouStateMachineBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\OmnipayBundle\SyliusOmnipayBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\MoneyBundle\SyliusMoneyBundle(),


    new Sylius\Bundle\OrderBundle\SyliusOrderBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\PricingBundle\SyliusPricingBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\SyliusProductBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\AssociationBundle\SyliusAssociationBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\ArchetypeBundle\SyliusArchetypeBundle(),

    new Sylius\Bundle\AttributeBundle\SyliusAttributeBundle(),
    new Sylius\Bundle\VariationBundle\SyliusVariationBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
    new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
    new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
);
```